# Service 500 exception response

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I am calling a webservice that is returning a 500 error:

```
using (var client = new PSGenericWebService.W_GENERICEMPLOYEEWS_PortTypeClient("GenericPort"))
{
    client.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new MessageBehavior("U", "P"));
    try
    {
        var response = client.GetEmployeeDataByDateRange();
        Console.WriteLine(response.Length);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

I understand the error has something to do with the date range and I ommitted some of the code to that respect. But using fiddler I get the following response:

> HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error Date: Tue, 18 Dec 2012 17:15:04 GMT
>   Content-Length: 732 Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
>   X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
        <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>
        <faultstring>null</faultstring>
        <detail>
            <IBResponse xmlns="" type="error">
                <DefaultTitle>Integration Broker Response</DefaultTitle>
                <StatusCode>20</StatusCode>
                <MessageID>74</MessageID>
                <DefaultMessage>
                    <![CDATA[From date (2012-11-17) and To date (2012-12-18) Range cannot be greater than 30 days. (27000,74)]]>
                </DefaultMessage>
                <MessageParameters>
                    <Parameter>
                        <![CDATA[2012-11-17]]>
                    </Parameter>
                    <Parameter>
                        <![CDATA[2012-12-18]]>
                    </Parameter>
                    <Parameter>
                        <![CDATA[30]]>
                    </Parameter>
                </MessageParameters>
            </IBResponse>
        </detail>
    </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The Exception that is returned is just listed as null.  I want to get the DefaultMessage from the returned XML.  So I am not looking for a fix to my code, I am looking at how to parse the returned response for the message I need.  Thank you.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking... the default message in what you posted is `From date (2012-11-17) and To date (2012-12-18) Range cannot be greater than 30 days. (27000,74)`.

Comment: I omitted that in the code to shorten it.  I am looking to handle the exception that is getting thrown.  If you write e.Message, it just returns the word null.  But using fiddler, I see the above response from the server.  If I correct the date range, then it returns a response and not an exception, I am more woried with getting the message from the exception.

Comment: That may be contained in the `InnerException`, or some other property of the exception. Try `e.ToString()` and see if anything looks right.

Comment: everything is null.  The inner exception is null, I tore through the debugger and could not find the information I was looking for.